# Adjusting vertical space around equation using \empheq package

Tags: empheq, colorbox

I have been using a simple method for adding a framed, colored box around important equations I want to highlight.  The empheq package has worked well.  However, I am having a lot of trouble figuring out the best way to add some vertical space around the frame.

Here is what I have done to create a new command called "myyellowonebox" -- the color is "myyellow1"

Preamble:

```
\definecolor{myyellow1}{RGB}{255, 255, 219}

\newcommand*\myyellowonebox[1]{%
\fcolorbox{myblue1}{myyellow1}{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}
```

And in the body, I have:

```
\begin{empheq}[box=\myyellowonebox]{equation}
 y = \frac{1}{4p} x^2
\end{empheq}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

However, I would like to add a larger gap above and below this equation.  I was able to add horizontal padding using the \hspace in the argument of \framebox.  But I can't seem to do the same for extra vertical space.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'd rather not use a fancy package, as this is about the sophistication I need for highlighting equations!

Comment: Since you're using `\fcolorbox`, adjust `\fboxsep`: `\setlength{\fboxsep}{<len>}`...

Comment: Thank you -- I tried that and it didn't seem to work.  Perhaps I did not put the command in the correct place.  Where would I insert the \setlength command as you suggested?

Comment: Add it in your preamble somewhere so it has the same effect across the whole document.

Comment: Thank you -- that seemed to work.  One last question -- is there a way to override this on an individual basis?

Answer (score 2):

`\fcolorbox` uses `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` as the widths of the `sep`aration and `rule`. So, adjusting that (globally) within the preamble would make for a consistent gap in your `\myyellowonebox`. You can adjust this locally as well and restore it as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,empheq}

\newcommand*\myyellowonebox[1]{\fcolorbox{blue!80}{yellow!15}{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}

\newlength{\fboxsave}\setlength{\fboxsave}{5pt}
\newcommand{\restorefboxsep}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{\fboxsave}}
\restorefboxsep% Default is 3.0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\myyellowonebox]{equation}
 y = \frac{1}{4p} x^2
\end{empheq}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}% Update \fboxsep
\begin{empheq}[box=\myyellowonebox]{equation}
 y = \frac{1}{4p} x^2
\end{empheq}
\restorefboxsep

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) worked -- thank you!  Here is the output I get when I add

```
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}
```

in the preamble.  It looks like

[image]

Now just trying to figure out how I can override this if I need to on an individual basis.